# How do you add Firebase/Firestore to an existing NestJS app inside of a NRWL monorepo?

Tags: firebase, nestjs, nrwl-nx

I'm building a monorepo with Angular and NestJS and am having a hard time figuring out what to do to properly add Firestore in the NestJS app.  First, most of what I've been coming across has us generate a new NestJS app with Firebase.  I came across [this tutorial](https://softwarebrothers.co/blog/setting-up-nestjs-with-firebase-functions/) which felt a little closer to my situation as they build the Nest app first then add Firebase afterwards.  However I'm still lost because it has us delete the functions folder that firebase installs then tells us to use the `package.json` file generated in the Nest app.  Due to me using NRWL the `package.json` file is the root package file for all the projects and I'm not sure of how to handle it.

I'm also getting an error in the `index.ts` file it tells us to create with this import

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
```

it can't find the file or figure out which file I'm suppose to put in its' place due to my setup being a little different from theirs.  I don't have any particular error messages or anything occurring, just more or less stuck trying to figure out how to go about this and haven't been able to find much about it tailored around NestJS.  Can someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - Create Nest App

```
nx generate @nrwl/nest:app myapp
```

Step 2 - Add Functions (not inside the `apps` folder).

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase init functions
```

Delete functions dir.

```
rm -rf functions
```

Now update the firebase config `firebase.json` to point to the nest app.

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "."
  }
}
```

Step 3 - Install Dependencies

```
npm i firebase-functions firebase-admin express @nestjs/platform-express
```

Step 4 - Update the package.json

Add the following lines to your package.json.

```
  "main": "dist/apps/myapp/main.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "<=10"
  }
```

Step 5 - Export the Server

Override the content inside your `apps/myapp/src/main.ts`.

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const server = express();

export const createNestServer = async (expressInstance) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance),
  );

  return app.init();
};

createNestServer(server)
    .then(v => console.log('Nest Ready'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Nest broken', err));

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

Step 6 - Build, Serve, Deploy

```
nx build myapp && firebase serve --only functions
```

Comment: ok I'm running into a problem with the last part.  First I got an error on the `-rm -rf` part saying `-rf` wasn't recognized.  I used `-fo` instead and it removed the folder.  Next I got an error saying `&&` was invalid so I eliminated it.  Then the `--only functions` part gave an error saying `--only` is an unknown option.  I tried `--only-functions` and got the same error so I just left it as `firebase serve` and I have a whole list of `module not found` errors because it can't resolve the paths to anything.

Comment: The `rm` command is only available for Linux distributions or based (also available on MAC). On Windows you can remove the generated `functions` folder generated by firebase. Make sure you're installing the firebase-tools;

Comment: I'm using VSCode for windows and I installed the firebase-tools as outlined in the tutorials as well as your post.  Nothing is being found.

Comment: I see on step #2 you emphasized `(not in apps folder)`.  I have it installed in the root folder of my backend app, is that correct?

Comment: yeah this isn't working out for me at all.  I uninstalled and re-installed it like 10 times since I last responded.  Can you be more specific about what folders I need to install things into and maybe tailor this more for windows machines?

Comment: Can you send me your Git repo? Maybe I can see what's happening exacly. Just after you init your functions remove the generated `functions` dir at the root of ya workspace and then target the `source` on `firebase.json` file.